# Accessing a javascript variable in the child html iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a parent document `index.php` that has `<iframe src="editor.html" width="400" height="300"></iframe>` Now file `editor.html` contains a javascript variable `editor` which I want to access in the parent window. I've tried to use what so called "session variable" which uses document window, but cannot access it.

The reason I must have two files like this is, the code editor fills the document. So that I have to put it in a separate page.

How to access this variable in child frame from the parent document?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a name for the `iframe`, then:

```
var windowObjectInIframe = window.frames['frame_name'];
```

If `editor` is a global variable in the iframe, you can access it like so:

```
var editorInMainPage = windowObjectInIframe.editor;
```

Comment: `windowObjectInIframe.editor` would give you the value